# OutOfMemoryException when loading large table into DataSet

Tags: devexpress, out-of-memory, gridcontrol, large-data

I would like retrieve data from a SQL Server table containing 2M records. I am using the Devexpress GridControl and have tried a simple code like this:

```
   DataTable dt = new DataTable();
   String sqlString = "select * from LARGETABLE left join TABLEB on LARGETABLE.ID=TABLEB.PARENTID";
   SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(sqlString, sqlConnection);
   da.Fill(dt);
   bindingSource1.DataSource = dt;
```

...

```
   gridControl1.DataSource = bindingSource1
```

When line da.Fill(dt) is executed, an **OutOfMemoryException** error is raised after sometime.

Microsoft Server Studio does load the table without problems and shows all 2M+ rows in the grid. Is it possible to build such a data browser in c# and load large data sets without running out of memory?

Answer (score 1):

I believe binding of `2M` records via the `BindingSource` and the 'DataTable' is not a good idea. Since you are using the DevExpress gridcontrol I suggest you use their **[server data-binding modes](http://help.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/CustomDocument8398)** (synchronous or asynchronous). You can read more about this concepts in "[Regular Binding Mode vs Regular Server Mode vs Instant Feedback Mode](http://help.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/CustomDocument2991)" article.
To start with Server-Mode please use the following How-To articles:
[Server Mode: Binding to Data Source Using 'LINQ to SQL Classes'](http://help.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/CustomDocument4057)